# How do I set the blur intensity of a system material in SwiftUI 3?

Tags: swiftui, blur, uiblureffect

SwiftUI 3 introduced the concept of system materials – akin to a `UIVisualEffectView` with a `UIBlurEffect`.

```swift
    Text("Hello world!")
        .padding()
        .background(.thinMaterial)
```

How do I change the intensity of blur applied by a system material?

Answer (score 1):

SwiftUI currently does not offer a way to achieve this. It is, however, possible to achieve using [SwiftUIX](https://github.com/SwiftUIX/SwiftUIX).

1. Install SwiftUIX via the [Swift Package Manager](https://github.com/SwiftUIX/SwiftUIX#installation).
2. In your code, `import SwiftUIX`.
3. Use `VisualBlurEffectView` with the `.intensity(_:)` modifier.

```swift
Text("Hello world!")
    .background {
        VisualEffectBlurView(blurStyle: .systemThinMaterial)
            .intensity(0.5)
    }
```

---

**Disclaimer**: Both this answer and the question were written to document SwiftUIX (an MIT-licensed open-source package) in a Q/A style format. As of writing this question I am currently not aware of any simple way to achieve this via UIKIt, and will gladly amend the answer to prescribe an official approach if/when one becomes available. I'd also love to just dump the code specific to this component, but it relies on a number of extensions/hacks that are spread across the SPM package that would be impractical to isolate just for the purpose of bundling a copy-paste solution to this answer.

Comment: You do not need a Package for such a simple thing! I am confused a little! You made that SPM, and why you asked this question?!

Comment: This is marketing @swiftPunk ahahaha

Comment: @RicoCrescenzio: hehehehe thanks! :)

Comment: @swiftPunk it's an MIT-licensed open source package already widely used by many folks, I have no monetary incentive to promote it. There's no official way to do this with SwiftUI right now (or `UIBlurEffect`) for that matter - I'll gladly amend my answer if you're aware of a better solution that doesn't rely on a package.

Comment: The point of asking and answering this question myself was to share knowledge/documentation about the framework in a Q/A style that is easily discoverable. See [this tweet](https://twitter.com/vatsal_manot/status/1440304610644664325?s=20) for more context.

Comment: @VatsalManot: It is not appreciate it that you want marketing your SPM with such way! Please stop it! Also there is an official way to use blur background in SwiftUI with UIViewrepresentable! I do not know what you mean by official! Is not UIViewrepresentable enough official for you? I did not look to your SPM, but I am telling you that you are using UIViewrepresentable for sure, like 100%! So what is the point?

Comment: @swiftPunk please point me to an official Apple API that allows you to change the *intensity* of a blur effect (not the alpha, the _intensity_). SwiftUIX wraps up a very messy UIKit workaround to this using property animators, so when I say that there is no official way to do it I mean that there is no official way to _change the intensity_ of a blur effect.